# Make Django Project Secret Keys accessible from Google Cloud

Tags: python, django, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a Django App running on Google Compute Engine VM instance. I am trying to store all the secret keys of settings.py file securely in the Google Cloud and then fetch those values in settings.py file.

I can store all the keys in either the VM's Metadata or Google Cloud Bucket. But I am not able to fetch these values in settings.py file.

For Example:
Let's say Settings.py is:

```
SECRET_KEY = "123-456-789"
CLIENT_SECRET_PATH = BASE_DIR + '/../client_secrets.p12'
```

Now, I can store SECRET_KEY variable in either Google VM's Metadata, or Google Datastore and the client_secrets.p12 file in Google Cloud Storage bucket. But I am not able to figure out how to fetch these values back in settings.py.

Can someone please suggest a good & efficient way to do this ?

Thanks,

Comment: Any suggestions please ?

Comment: I have your problem too. Did you find any solution?